# Excel formula to return a cell's custom format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to normalize data by reading a custom number format.  The actual data in the following cells only have the values 3 and 33

```
[A1]  3 CASES
[A2]  33 UNITS
```

The terms "CASES" and "UNITS" are displayed because they are part of the custom format distinct to each cell.  e.g. 
A1 has custom number format code:  # "CASES", and A2 has custom number format code: # "UNITS"

I would like to normalize this data via an excel formula into UNITS for reporting purposes.  I attempted to use the formula

```
=CELL("format",A1)
```

but the value returned is F0 instead of: # "CASES"

If each CASE has 5 units I am expecting to have an additional column that computes NORMALIZED UNITS with a formula that reads something like:

```
=IF(CELL("format",A1)="CASES",5*A1,A1)
```

This way the NORMALIZED UNITS in column B would be

```
[B1]  15
[B2]  33
```

Comment: Accepting defeat and will utilize a user defined function.  Moved the "CASE" comparison into an excel equation though for easier debugging/adaptability.  Hope this helps the next person...  
  
[B1] =IF(IFERROR(FIND(" CASES",numberformat($A1)),FALSE),5*$A1,$A1)  
  
>Public Function numberFormat(rgCell As Range) As String
>    numberFormat = rgCell.numberFormat
>End Function'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a custom function.

```
Function get_format(r As Range) As String

get_format = r.NumberFormat

End Function
```

Then use

`=if(get_format(a1)="# " & CHAR(34) & "CASE" & CHAR(34),5,*A1,1)`

Or you could just check to see if the word CASE is in the number format

```
Function check_case(r As Range) As Boolean

check_case = InStr(1, r.NumberFormat, "CASE")

End Function
```

`=if(check_case(A1),5,*A1,1)`

Comment: appreciate the answer, but was hoping to avoid a user-defined function.

Answer (score 2):

Build a user-defined function by copying the attached code in your workbook module, you can then use it in your worksheet as `=if(iscase(a1),5,1)*a1`

```
Function IsCase(rgCell As Range) As Boolean
If InStr(UCase(rgCell.NumberFormat), "CASE") > 0 Then
    IsCase = True
Else
    IsCase = False
End If

End Function
```

Comment: appreciate the answer, but was hoping to avoid a user-defined function.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to address it without either a user-defined function or creating a column where you'd type the unit manually. You're starting with data that's not really in an ideal format.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to solve this issue as well.
Possible solution using old Excel 4 macro function.

Press *CTRL-F3* to get macro editor up, create new macro and give it a name like *ExtractUnits*

In the refers to box, enter

```
=GET.CELL(53,OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,-1))
```

In the cell to the right of the data (in this case column B), enter

```
=ExtractUnits
```

It is really, really slow to calculate, but is getting me the data out as text.
Mine is all the same length, so I use right to extract the units, but you could find the space and parse.
 If you want a different cell, change the offset parameters.